# Unable to switch node version with NVM

Tags: node.js, npm, homebrew, nvm

I can't seem to switch my current node version using `nvm`

Here's my output from `nvm debug`

```js
nvm --version: v0.37.2
$TERM_PROGRAM: vscode
$SHELL: /bin/bash
$SHLVL: 2
whoami: 'john'
${HOME}: /Users/john
${NVM_DIR}: '${HOME}/.nvm'
${PATH}: /usr/local/homebrew/opt/python3.8/bin:/usr/local/bin/node:${HOME}/.symfony/bin:${HOME}/.composer/vendor/bin:/usr/bin/python2.7:/usr/local/homebrew/bin:/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin:${NVM_DIR}/versions/node/v10.3.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/usr/local/homebrew/opt/python3.8/bin:/usr/local/bin/node:${HOME}/.symfony/bin:${HOME}/.composer/vendor/bin:/usr/bin/python2.7:/usr/local/homebrew/bin:/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin
$PREFIX: ''
${NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX}: ''
$NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR: ''
$NVM_IOJS_ORG_MIRROR: ''
shell version: 'GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin20)'
uname -a: 'Darwin 20.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 20.3.0: Thu Jan 21 00:07:06 PST 2021; root:xnu-7195.81.3~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64'
checksum binary: 'shasum'
OS version: macOS 11.2 20D64
curl: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/curl, curl 7.52.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0) libcurl/7.52.1 OpenSSL/1.0.2j zlib/1.2.8
wget: not found
sed: /usr/bin/sed
cut: /usr/bin/cut
basename: /usr/bin/basename
rm: /bin/rm
mkdir: /bin/mkdir
xargs: /usr/bin/xargs
git: /usr/local/bin/git, git version 2.16.2
grep: /usr/bin/grep, grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD
awk: /usr/bin/awk, awk version 20200816
nvm current: system
which node: /usr/local/homebrew/bin/node
which iojs: 
which npm: /usr/local/homebrew/bin/npm
npm config get prefix: /usr/local/homebrew
npm root -g: /usr/local/homebrew/lib/node_modules
```

I can use `brew` to switch my node version, but I can only switch the major version of node.
I can run `brew link node@10` and it does change to node version 10.  However, I want node version 10.3.0 which I can't swith to it via brew.

NVM
I can install the node with `nvm install 10.3.0` and I can run `nvm use 10.3.0`
However, when I open a new terminal and run `node -v` it show me a different version of node.
Here's the output of `nvm list`

```js
        v8.10.0
        v10.3.0
        v10.9.0
        v11.0.0
       v14.15.5
        v15.8.0
->       system
default -> 11.0.0 (-> v11.0.0)
iojs -> N/A (default)
unstable -> N/A (default)
node -> stable (-> v15.8.0) (default)
stable -> 15.8 (-> v15.8.0) (default)
lts/* -> lts/fermium (-> v14.15.5)
lts/argon -> v4.9.1 (-> N/A)
lts/boron -> v6.17.1 (-> N/A)
lts/carbon -> v8.17.0 (-> N/A)
lts/dubnium -> v10.23.3 (-> N/A)
lts/erbium -> v12.20.2 (-> N/A)
lts/fermium -> v14.15.5
```

Comment: What's the output when you execute `nvm use 10.3`?

Answer (score 4):

I've now found a solution.  I have to uninstall node from homebrew, because homebrew control the node version.  Once I uninstall and delete all related node files from homebrew, I can use nvm to switch my node version.

Answer (score -1):

Try disabling and then enabling nvm. After that, you should be able to switch to any installed node version.

```
nvm off
nvm on
nvm use [any node version].
```

Now try one of the following commands to check that node is working and its version:

```
node -v OR nvm list OR nvm current
```

If it still doesn't work, try running your cmd as administrator. Search for cmd and click "run as administrator"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZiiT.jpg)

Comment: off or on are not listen within nvm usage help, and trying to use gives nothing but help screen. Maybe they were before, but as of nvm v0.39.1 they are not present.